# Web hosting with HTTP/1.1 Protocol GET

Tags: http, http-1.1

I am on an Arduino project with `ESP8266 Wifi` module.

I have been successful so far in getting `200 OK` response from `www.google.com/#q=random+search`

I was also successful at getting `200 OK` response from the

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: randomName.hazelhosting.com
```

However I have no idea why the server throw me a `404 Not found` code whenever I try with the files in the host. For example

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: randomName.hazelhosting.com
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "why it throw"? What is this "it"? The arduino? Some code you're running on arduino?

Comment: @MarcB hey it was the server, hazelhosting